# Why OR in where condition is not working on mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Why OR in where condition is not working on mysql

Here is Query:

```
select CONCAT(D.did, ',', 'tbl_doctors') AS ID ,D.name,(S.name) As spname, D.addr 
FROM medicaldoctor.tbl_doctors D 
LEFT JOIN medicaldoctor.tbl_my_special M ON D.did = M.did 
LEFT JOIN medicaladmin.tbl_specialization S ON M.sid = S.id 
WHERE (D.addr LIKE '%Pune%' AND D.addr LIKE '%kothrud%') 
AND (S.name LIKE "%a%" OR D.name LIKE "%a%") 
group by D.addr
```

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: getting error or if I solve error using brackets getting all search result without sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query works as coded.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS D,M,S;
    CREATE TABLE D(DID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), ADDR VARCHAR(20));
    CREATE TABLE M(DID INT, SID INT);
    CREATE TABLE S(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20));

    INSERT INTO D VALUES(1,'AAA',',pUNE,KOTHRUD'),(2,'BAB',',pune,KOTHRUD'),(3,'CCC',',PUNE,,KOTHRUD');
    INSERT INTO M VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,1);
    INSERT INTO S VALUES(1,'XXX'),(2,'YYY');

    select CONCAT(D.did, ',', 'tbl_doctors') AS ID ,D.name,(S.name) As spname, D.addr 
    FROM  D 
    LEFT JOIN  M ON D.did = M.did 
    LEFT JOIN  S ON M.sid = S.id 
    WHERE (D.addr LIKE '%Pune%' AND D.addr LIKE '%kothrud%') 
    AND (S.name LIKE "%a%" OR D.name LIKE "%a%") 
    group by D.addr

+---------------+------+--------+---------------+
| ID            | name | spname | addr          |
+---------------+------+--------+---------------+
| 1,tbl_doctors | AAA  | XXX    | ,pUNE,KOTHRUD |
+---------------+------+--------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The group by is free to select either of the 2 doctors and either of the 2 specialties for dr 1 , this is expected and documented behaviour https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html - *If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.*